# How to calculate $P[X\in A|\sin(X)=y]$?

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with density function $f(x)$. We know how to compute $$P[X\in A|X=x]=I_A(x)$$
But how to calculate, for example, $P[X\in A|\sin(X)=y]$?

I think it could be like this:
$$P_{X\circ sin(X)}(A\times B)=P(X\in A\cap sin(X) \in B)=P(X\in A\cap  arcsin(B))=$$
$$=\int_{ arcsin(B)}I_A(x)f(x)dx=I_1+I_2$$
$$I_1= \int_{(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\cap arcsin(B)} \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}I_A(x+2k\pi)f(x+2k\pi)dx=$$
$$= \int_{(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\cap arcsin(B)} \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x+2k\pi)I_A(x+2k\pi)}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(x+2k\pi)+f(-x+(2k+1)\pi)]}\cdot$$
$$\cdot\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(x+2k\pi)+f(-x+(2k+1)\pi)]dx=$$
$$=\int_{B}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x+2k\pi)I_A(x+2k\pi)}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(x+2k\pi)+f(-x+(2k+1)\pi)]}dP_{sin(X)}$$
Same $I_2$ with $f(-x+(2k+1)\pi)I_A(-x+(2k+1)\pi)$. Therefore:
$$P[X\in A|sin(X)=y]=$$
$$=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(\arcsin(y)+2k\pi)I_A(\arcsin(y)+2k\pi)}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(\arcsin(y)+2k\pi)+f(-\arcsin(y)+(2k+1)\pi)]}+$$
$$+\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(-\arcsin(y)+(2k+1)\pi)I_A(-\arcsin(y)+(2k+1)\pi)}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(\arcsin(y)+2k\pi)+f(-\arcsin(y)+(2k+1)\pi)]}$$
As an example, let's look at $A=(-\pi/2,\pi /2)$:
$$P[X\in(-\pi/2,\pi /2)|sin(X)=y]=$$
$$=\frac{f(\arcsin(y))}{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(\arcsin(y)+2k\pi)+f(-\arcsin(y)+(2k+1)\pi)]}$$

Comment: Re the edit: if $B,$ as it appears, is intended to be a set like $\{x\mid \sin(x)=y\},$ then you are lost at the outset because that set has measure zero, making the integral automatically zero.  It turns out the sine is very, very special insofar as the magnitude of its derivative at the points of $B$ is constant. The error of this approach becomes more apparent when you try to apply it to a function without this property.  Consider a simpler case, such as $f(x)=x+2|x|,$ to get a feel for this kind of problem.

Comment: Both $A$ and $B$ are measurable subsets of $R$, although only their intersection with the interval $(-1,1)$ matters for $B$. The integral extends to all values of $x$ such that $sin(x)\in B$, and in principle does not have to be zero.

Comment: In principle it is *exactly* zero unless you contemplate a noncontinuous distribution for $X,$ which would contradict your assumption of a density function.

Comment: Suppose $A=R$, $B=(-1,1)$ then $\int_{\arcsin(B)}I_A(x)f(x)dx=\int_R f(x)dx=1$

Comment: I asked you in my first comment what $B$ is and mentioned that according to what's in your question, it's a set of measure zero.  The interval $B=(-1,1)$ does not correspond with the condition "$\sin(X)=y$" appearing in your formulas.

Comment: I don't know what correspondence you mean. What correspondence must there be between $B$ and $sin(X)=y$?

Comment: In order to make any sense of your post, we need to understand what you might be asking about.  You appear to switch back and forth between conditioning on an undefined "$B$" and conditioning on "$\sin(X)=y.$" You need to communicate your question if you want answers.

Comment: I want to calculate $P[X\in A|sin(X)]$ or what is the same $E[I_{x\in A}|sin(X)]$. What you do not understand?

Comment: I do not understand why you refuse to clarify your question to make it unambiguous and answerable.  That is not a constructive way to interact with our site.  You have, though, made it abundantly clear that my efforts to help you formulate an effective question are to no avail, so I will end them here.

Comment: The notation used in the OP's calculations seems a bit non-standard and messy. There are also some gaps in the logic/reasoning. However, the core question seems unambiguous.

Comment: @S.Catterall Is the core question about conditioning on an event of measure zero or one of positive measure?  The answers will be almost totally different, so IMHO it's important to get that distinction cleared up at the outset.

Comment: @whuber To me, the core question seems to be about conditioning on a set of measure zero. However, to get to an answer to that core question, the OP then considers an arbitrary set $B$, using a method apparently similar to that detailed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979476/obtain-the-conditional-distribution-of-x-given-x2-t/3980276#3980276

Comment: I agree with @S.Catterall -- the core question: determine $P(X \in A | \sin(X))$
 is unambiguous (I think we can focus on solving this instead of $P(X \in A | \sin(X) = y)$ which can be viewed as the value of $P(X \in A | \sin(X))_\omega$ on the set $\{\omega: \sin(X(\omega)) = y\}$). What are ambiguous are OP's attempts (including non-standard notations and unnecessary complications).

Comment: @Zhanxiong I think the OP's calculations are messy but ultimately it seems like they reached the correct answer

Comment: @S.Catterall The format looks promising, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Your first line of the "I think it could be like this" block is wrong.  You have $P(X \in A \cap \arcsin B)$, but the correct expression is $P(X \in A \cap \arcsin B | X \in \arcsin B)$

Comment: @S.Catterall I realize this is a long comment thread, but in an early comment I pointed out that getting the correct answer this way might have been a matter of luck, because the absolute value of the derivative is constant along the inverse image of $y$ no matter what value $y$ might have.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's calculations look broadly correct to me, but much of the reasoning behind the calculations has not been included in the question. So I will try to fill in some of the gaps in the OP's presentation.

The aim is to calculate $P[X\in A|\sin(X)=y]$ where the random variable $X$ has density $f$. Let $\arcsin(y)$ denote the number $z\in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ such that $\sin(z)=y$. Let $\sin^{-1}y$ denote the *set* of all real $z$ such that $\sin(z)=y$. Then $P[X\in \sin^{-1}y]=0$ so we are conditioning on a set of probability zero. This means that the 'elementary' conditional probability definition is not available to us. Instead, I interpret $P[X\in A|\sin(X)=y]$ via regular conditional distributions as detailed in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498338/43949). The relevant quantity for us is $P_{X\mid Y}[A\mid y]:=P^Y[X\in A\mid y]$ where $A$ is a Borel set, $Y=\sin(X)$ and $y$ is a real number. Think of it as a function of both $A$ and $y$.

The key defining property of $P_{X\mid Y}[A\mid y]$ is that $$\int_B P_{X\mid Y}[A\mid y]\,P_Y(\mathrm dy)=P[\{Y\in B\}\cap\{X\in A\}]$$ for any Borel $A$ and $B$. By uniqueness of the regular conditional distribution, if we can find a quantity $g(A,y)$ such that $$\int_B  g(A,y)\,P_Y(\mathrm dy)=P[\{Y\in B\}\cap\{X\in A\}]$$ then we can conclude that, in fact, $g(A,y)$ is the required conditional probability. This approach is used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979476/obtain-the-conditional-distribution-of-x-given-x2-t/3980276#3980276) to handle a similar problem but with $\sin(X)$ replaced by $X^2$. In our case, we might guess that $$g(A,y)=\frac{\sum_{z\in A\,\cap\,\sin^{-1}y} f(z)}{\sum_{z\in\,\sin^{-1}y} f(z)}$$

It turns out that we can replicate the approach at the previously referenced answer using this guess, and the calculations turn out to be essentially those presented by the OP. One point to note is that we require an expression for the density function of $\sin(X)$. This can be obtained from the cdf in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609543/distribution-function-of-sin-x-where-x-is-a-random-variable) by differentiating. This gives you an infinite sum that appears in the OP's expressions.

In general there are some problems with this approach as applied to the transformation $T(X)=\sin(X)$. Firstly, the denominator of the guess $g(A,y)$ could be zero or infinity, which means that this quantity may not always be defined everywhere. This may be less of a problem if the density $f$ is restricted in some way e.g. it should be OK if $f$ is a Gaussian density.

There is also a second problem, as highlighted by @whuber. The transformations $T(X)=\sin(X)$ and $T(X)=X^2$ share an interesting property: if $T(x_1)=T(x_2)$ then $|T'(x_1)|=|T'(x_2)|$. This property allows the 'guess' to take on a particularly simple form as above. If this property fails to hold then the 'guess' will also need to take into account information about the derivative of the transformation.

Comment: Please see my comment to the first answer.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comments, especially regarding the function $f$ such that $\Pr(X\mid f(X)=y)$ does not exist at a countable set of $y$. I thought that there was a theorem guaranteeing the existence of regular conditional distributions, so I'm wondering how this example can be reconciled with that existence? I can see that there are some issues with the approach above e.g. the denominator of $g$ above could potentially be zero or infinity depending on the choice of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A$ and $\arcsin(B)$ are sets with measure > 0, we can write:

$$P(X \in A | \sin(X) \in B) = P(X \in (A \cap \arcsin(B)) | X \in \arcsin(B))$$

This is easily seen to be:

$$P(X \in A | \sin(X) \in B) = {P(X \in (A \cap \arcsin(B)) \over P(X \in \arcsin(B))} $$

For example, let $X \sim U(0,10)$, $A = [0, 1]$, and $B = [0,1]$.  We have:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\arcsin(B) &=& [0, \pi/2] \\
A \cap \arcsin(B) &=& [0, 1] \\
P(X \in (A \cap \arcsin(B)) &=& \int_0^1f(x)dx = {1\over 10}\int_0^1 dx={1 \over 10} \\
P(X \in \arcsin(B)) &=& \int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)dx = {1\over 10}\int_0^{\pi/2} dx={\pi \over 20} 
\end{eqnarray}$$

and, finally,

$$P(X \in  (A \cap \arcsin(B)) | X \in \arcsin(B)) = {{1 \over 10} \over {\pi \over 20}} = {2 \over \pi} \approx 0.6366198 $$

Comment: This approach gets the correct answer for the easy (uninteresting) interpretation of the question; namely, where $\Pr(\sin(X)\in B)\gt 0.$  The interesting version of the question concerns the answer when this probability is zero.  It gets truly interesting when functions other than the sine are involved. To appreciate the problem, note that given $X,$ I believe one can construct an everywhere differentiable, bounded function $f$ for which $\Pr(X\mid f(X)=y)$ *does not exist* for a *dense, countable* set of values $y.$

Comment: @whuber - yes, $B$ countable or finite in the example above would be something beyond what I've had to think about...  I guess you could extend your problem statement to allow a supplemental construction of a probability function with the same relative values at $B$ as whatever the original density's values were, but that's hardly contained within my limited knowledge of probability theory.

Comment: It's actually just a slight generalization of the usual change of variable formula -- it doesn't seem to require sophisticated probability concepts.  The non-existence result I alluded to applies to any continuous unbounded random variable $X.$ The point is that if you try to define a conditional distribution in the natural, intuitive way you can find yourself assigning greater relative probabilities to greater numbers, essentially pushing the distribution out to infinity.  I find thinking about this to be very instructive.

Comment: @whuber - yeah, now I'm sitting at my desk thinking about it instead of working out as I had intended to!

Answer (score 0):

How to calculate $E[X|(X^2-1)^2] $:
\begin{gather*}
P_{X\circ (X^2-1)^2}(A \times B)=P(X\in A\cap (X^2-1)^2\in B)=P\left( X\in A\cap(\sqrt{\sqrt {B}+1}\right)=\\[10pt]
=\displaystyle\int\limits_{\sqrt{\sqrt {B}+1}}f(x)I_A(x)dx=\int\limits_B \frac{\sum f(x_i)I_A(x_i)/|4x_i(x_i^2-1)|}{\sum f(x_i)/|4x_i(x_i^2-1)|}dP_{(X^2-1)^2}
\end{gather*}
Therefore:
\begin{gather*}
P[X\in A|(X^2-1)^2=y]=\frac {\sum f(x_i)I_A(x_i)/|4x_i(x_i^2-1)|}{\sum f(x_i)/|4x_i(x_i^2-1)|}=\frac {\sum f(x_i)I_A(x_i)/|x_i|}{\sum f(x_i)/|x_i|}
\end{gather*}
Being:
\begin{gather*}
x_1=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{y}};\hspace{30pt} x_2=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{y}};\hspace{30pt} x_3=-x_2;\hspace{30pt} x_4=-x_1
\end{gather*}
Then:
\begin{gather*}
E[X|(X^2-1)^2=y]=\frac{f(x_1)-f(-x_1)+f(x_2)-f(-x_2)}{(f(x_1)+f(-x_1))/x_1+(f(x_2)+f(-x_2))/x_2}
\end{gather*}
And substituting $(X^2-1)^2$ by $y$, we get:
\begin{gather*}
E[X|(X^2-1)^2]=E[X||(X^2-1)|]=\\[10pt]
=\frac{f(\sqrt{X^2})-f(-\sqrt{X^2})+f(\sqrt{2-X^2})-f(-\sqrt{2-X^2})}{(f(\sqrt{X^2})+f(-\sqrt{X^2}))/\sqrt{X^2}+(f(\sqrt{2-X^2})+f(-\sqrt{2-X^2}))/\sqrt{2-X^2}}
\end{gather*}
Another interesting example:
\begin{gather*}
E[X|min(X,Y)=u]=\frac{\displaystyle\int_u^\infty
\hspace{-10pt}u\, dP_{Y/X}(u)\;f(u)+\displaystyle\int_u^\infty
\hspace{-10pt}x\, dP_{X/Y}(u)\;g(u)}{\displaystyle\int_u^\infty
\hspace{-10pt}dP_{Y/X}(u)\;f(u)+\displaystyle\int_u^\infty
\hspace{-10pt}dP_{X/Y}(u)\;g(u)}
\end{gather*}

Comment: Although the answer is accidentally correct, the method is not.  For instance, this method would obtain the wrong conditional distribution for the function $f(x)=x+2|x|.$

Comment: Do you believe?. $f(x)=x+2|x|$ is not a density function, at least over $R$.

Comment: We are talking about the transformation, not the density!

Comment: I see, you mean $P[X\in A|g(X)=y]$ with $g(x)=x+2|x|$. Is it so? In that case the result would be:
$\frac{f(\frac{y}{3})}{f(\frac{y}{3})+f(-y)}I_A(\frac{y}{3})+\frac{f(-y)}{f(\frac{y}{3})+f(-y)}I_A(y)$

Comment: Good!  Although it's unclear what you mean by $f,$ the form of your formula begins to look familiar.  But that nicely illustrates my point, because (unless I misunderstand what you mean by $f$) it's incorrect.  The relative weights on the two-point support of the conditional distribution should be $3$ and $1$ rather than being equal.

Comment: You are right, there was an error, the correct is:
$P[X\in A|g(X)=y]=\frac{f(\frac{y}{3})}{f(\frac{y}{3})+3f(-y)}I_A(\frac{y}{3})+\frac{3f(-y)}{f(\frac{y}{3})+3f(-y)}I_A(-y)$

Comment: The solution in your last example is incorrect.  For instance, when $(X^2-1)^2=1$ the conditional distribution is a *constant* at zero.  When $(X^2-1)^2=0$ the conditional distribution is Rademacher.  Indeed, your first equality, removing the square on $(X^2-1)$ in the condition, is invalid.

Comment: The formula is valid. Do you want a demo?

Comment: I don't need a demonstration.  I have checked my assertions.  *You* need to demonstrate you are correct, which you have not done merely by asserting a result.

Comment: I will delete my previous answer and replace it with the proof of my claim, if that's okay with you.

Comment: That would be good to see, thank you.

Comment: Are your doubts cleared?

Comment: I have no doubts: this answer remains incorrect in the special cases I indicated, and I pointed that out because there's much to learn from considering what the answer ought to be in those cases.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Division by zero.

Comment: Division by zero and by complex numbers, great!